# Excel Match function with columns having R1C1 reference style

Tags: string, excel, reference, match, excel-formula

I am using excel to look through my data, I have a matrix of 2000 columns and thousands of rows.
I want to search for some string in a specific column. I've been reading online and the `Match()` function is usually used for this. I am not sure of 2 things actually:

1-how to formulate the command since I have my columns as R1C1 reference style? (I mean I have numbers instead of letters as columns names)

2- I don't know how many rows I have, I just want the function to search the entire column for this string.
Here's the command I found, which doesn't solve any of the 2 problems mentioned above

```
=MATCH("string",A1:A100, 0)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why not change it to A1 Style. It takes few seconds to do it. Once you have written the formula, change it back to R1C1 if you are comfortable with that look? Also if you do not know the total rows then use `A:A` instead of `A1:A100`

Comment: Thanks for the A:A hint. But I would like to keep my columns in the R1C1 reference style. as I need this to reference it in another program. There must be some way to do that in the R1C1 style, this is some basic command :D

Comment: have you tried to just create the formula by pointing to the required range with your mouse when filling in the arguments?

Comment: From my comment above.... `Once you have written the formula, change it back to R1C1`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018751/how-to-switch-off-r1c1-reference-style-in-excel-2007

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I need to do this like 200 times to check on many strings, do I have to change it every time I am looking for 1 string? I hope there's a shorter way. If not, I'll have to change it after each string I find.

Comment: No once you know how excel formula works, you will not have to change it every time. You will automatically type the formula in R1C1 ;)

Comment: hahhaha, alright, I'll do my best... but I won't submit an answer for now. You never know, we might both end up learning how to do this in the R1C1 style. Thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: `You never know, we might both end up learning how to do this in the R1C1 style.` Er, I already know how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple one:

```
=MATCH("string",A:A,0)
```

However, the preferred technique is to usually create a named reference. Then you can just use the name of the range that you want to search in your `MATCH()` formula. Named ranges are usually easier to work with in larger projects (or projects that start small but where you want to keep some flexibility in case the workbook gets larger).

**Edit:** If you want to stick to R1C1, the formula might look like this instead: `=MATCH("string",C1,0)`

Comment: Ah! Missed your comment while I was editing to put the R1C1 version. Basically, replace the `A:A` with `C1` or whatever appropriate column number (C[+x] works for relative refs too).